# How to Change the form size in case of label text overflow?

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

First, I'am Sorry.
I'm not good at English.

I'm making custom messagebox.
I want to change messagebox form size in case of UltraLabel text overflow.
But, I don't know what to do.

I tried the following a way.

```
Form.AutoSize = true;
Form.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
Panel.AutoSize = true;
Panel.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
```

Label is in the Panel.

Help me, What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should calculate the size of text using WinApi functions. Or other methods, for example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9855d7e6-264e-4d1f-bd7d-35381732d8c7/how-to-calculate-the-width-and-height-of-a-string-in-c-class-library?forum=csharpgeneral

Then you can calculate the size of label that is should be. Next having that size you can resize your form.

Comment: I couldn't imagine it. Thank you!